# Adding images on to canvas when Onclick on the canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

Currently I have setup a canvas, and I'm trying to add some images onto it.

So only when i Onclick on the canvas, a small images will then appear on the position that i clicked on the canvas.

Can anybody able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to keep in mind is that you'll need to capture the coordinates with respect to the canvas, not the entire page, which is exactly what you'll get from the onclick event. This is fairly easy to translate, with code such as this:

```
var onMouseClick = function(evt){
    var x, y;
    var point = findOffset(e.target);
    x = e.pageX - point.x;
    y = e.pageY - point.y;

    return {x,y};
}


var findOffset = function(element) {
    var left = 0;
    var top = 0;
    if (element.offsetParent) {
        do {
            top += element.offsetTop;
            left += element.offsetLeft;
        } while(element = element.offsetParent);
        return {
            x : left,
            y : top
        };
    }
};
```

Where your onMouseClick callback returns an object with the x,y position that the click occurred in your canvas itself.

Next, you'll want to insert your image at this point. How you do this is going to depend somewhat on where your image source, is but it will basically look like:

```
var canvasCtx = document.getElementById("myCanvasElement").getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementById("id-of-an-img-tag-in-your-DOM");
canvasCtx.drawImage(img,x,y);
```

If you want to load your image from somewhere besides the DOM, you can construct the image object yourself like so:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    canvasCtx.drawImage(img,x,y);
};

img.src = "url/to/your/image.jpg";
```

This will cause your image to be loaded from a URL on mouse-click, then once the image finishes loading, adds it to your canvas.

Comment: "id-of-an-img-tag-in-your-DOM" refers to the id of a <img> tag someone in your HTML. If that's not where you're getting your image from, then don't use that. Instead, use the "var img = new Image()" snippet of code to load your image from a URL.

Comment: @BrandonDockery. Check out the element.getBoundingClientRect method which is a simpler way to get the offsets of the canvas.  This method has the advantage of accounting for scrolling. ;-)

Comment: @markE Hi, do you know how to do it with your method?

Comment: var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); var offsetX=BB.left; var offsetY=BB.top;

Comment: @Bernard, Here's a demo using `getBoundingClientRect`:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/WFW47/

Comment: If you want mouseX & mouseY to be available outside handleMousemove then you must declare them outside handleMousemove (variables declared inside a function are only available--only "scoped", inside that function.  You also have to allow for the possibility that the mouse is outside the canvas element.  Here's your fiddle refactored for these issues: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/pwXbP/  Cheers!